# Pass is NULL instead of = Null

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sqldatasource

This is my sqldatasource

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="get_client_users" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:local %>" SelectCommand="SELECT *  FROM users WHERE clientid = @clientid" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="clientid" Type="Int32"  ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"/>
    </SelectParameters>
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now I want is that when clientid is null then it should return all the rows with clientid=null, but when I watch the query passed in profiler i get this.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT *  FROM users WHERE clientid = @clientid',N'@clientid int',@clientid=NULL
```

but it will only return values if its

```
clientid is NULL
```

As I have ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" command is executing, but returning empty dataset.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question....`null` and `NULL` are the same thing in T-SQL, as far as I know.  The profiler is simply capitalizing all the keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT *
FROM users 
WHERE ISNULL(clientID, -1) = ISNULL(@ClientID, -1)
```

This is assuming that clientID will never be -1 in the database.

Comment: `NULLIF`? I might have expected `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` and the use of an otherwise non-existent ID value, but `NULLIF` surprises me. What's the thinking here?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, you're correct, it should be `ISNULL` NOT `NULLIF`. I've updated my post.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, wouldn't my code do the same thing as in your answer? If not, can you please explain why it would be better to use your approach as opposed to mine?

Comment: This also requires that `1` isn't a valid `clientID` value, otherwise it will also return those rows when `@ClientID` is null. (Oh, and it negates any possible use of an index on the `ClientID` column)

Comment: So I would rather then update it to a negative value, assuming that clientID is not negative?

Comment: I added 0 instead of 1 as it will never be is my database. also one can use -1

Answer (score 0):

Since you have complete control over the `SELECT` command, I'd have thought:

```
SELECT *  FROM users
WHERE clientid = @clientid OR
      (@clientid is null and clientid is null)
```

Would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
@ClientID IS NULL OR ClientID=@ClientID
```

Comment: This will cause to return values all rows when clientid is null

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT *
FROM users 
WHERE clientID = ISNULL(@ClientID, clientID)
```